# My App is getting crash when i click continuously on start and stop action. I am working with speech recognition

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my class code i am using Speech framework to implement speech to text conversion. But whenever i press stop_start action continuously my app get crashed and i get this error- `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest cannot be re-used'`.

```
import UIKit
import Speech

class ViewController: UIViewController ,SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {
    
    //MARK:- IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewAudioText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn_start: UIButton!
    
    //MARK: - Local Properties
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    let speechReconizer : SFSpeechRecognizer? = SFSpeechRecognizer()
    let requestSFSpeech = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    var task : SFSpeechRecognitionTask!
    var isStart : Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.requestPermission()
    }
    
    func requestPermission(){
        self.btn_start.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                if authStatus == SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                    print("Accepted")
                    self.btn_start.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                } else if authStatus == .denied{
                    print("user denied permission")
                } else if authStatus == .notDetermined{
                    print("Device does not have functionality")
                } else if authStatus == .restricted{
                    print("user restricted")
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

//MARK:- UIBUtton Action
extension ViewController{
    @IBAction func actionGetTextFromAudio(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.convertAudioFileToText()
    }
    
    @IBAction func btn_start_stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //MARK:- Coding for start and stop sppech recognization...!
        self.isStart = !self.isStart
        if self.isStart {
            self.convertSpeechToText()
            self.btn_start.setTitle("STOP", for: .normal)
            self.btn_start.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        } else {
            self.cancelSpeechRecognization()
            self.btn_start.setTitle("START", for: .normal)
            self.btn_start.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        }
    }
}


//MARK:- METHOD CONVERT AUDIO TO TEXT
extension ViewController {
    
    func convertAudioFileToText() {            
        let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test1", withExtension: "mp3")
        
        let extractedExpr: SFSpeechRecognizer? = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
        let recognizer = extractedExpr
        let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioURL!)
        
        request.shouldReportPartialResults = true
        
        if (recognizer?.isAvailable)! {
            recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
                guard error == nil else { print("Error: \(error!)"); return }
                guard let result = result else { print("No result!"); return }
                
                print(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
                self.textViewAudioText.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            }
        } else {
            print("Device doesn't support speech recognition")
        }
    }
    
    /*
     1. First get audio url from where you have store audio file.
     2. Then create instance of SFSpeechRecognizer with locale that you have want.
     3. Create instance of SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest which are used to requesting recognitionTask.
     
     4.  recognitionTask will give you result and error. Where result contains bestTranscription.formattedString. formmatedString is your test result of audio file.
     
     5.  If set request.shouldReportPartialResults = true,
     this will give your partial result of every line speak in audio.
     */
    
    
}



extension ViewController{
    //MARK: UPDATED FUNCTION
    
    func cancelSpeechRecognization() {
        task.finish()
        requestSFSpeech.endAudio()
        audioEngine.stop()
        
        if audioEngine.inputNode.numberOfInputs > 0 {
            audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        }
        self.textViewAudioText.text = ""
    }
    
    
    func convertSpeechToText() {
        let node = audioEngine.inputNode
        let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        
        node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, _) in
            self.requestSFSpeech.append(buffer)
        }
        
        audioEngine.prepare()
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error comes here for starting the audio listner \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        guard let myRecognization = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
            print("Recognization is not allow on your local")
            return
        }
        
        if !myRecognization.isAvailable {
            print("Recognization is free right now, Please try again after some time.")
        }
        
        task = speechReconizer?.recognitionTask(with: requestSFSpeech, resultHandler: { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else {
                if error != nil {
                    print(error.debugDescription)
                    
                }else {
                    print("Problem in giving the response")
                }
                return
            }
            
            let message = response.bestTranscription.formattedString
            print("Message : \(message)")
            self.textViewAudioText.text = message
        })
    }
    
}
```

Comment: To make your question on-topic, you need to [edit] it to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: hello i am not able to put My class code here..how can i go for that??

Comment: What do you mean you can't put your code here? If it's confidential, you need to create a [mcve] that you can share here.

Comment: i have shared my class code above...pls check the link

Comment: You need to include all relevant code __in the body of your question__, not in a 3rd party website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might need to stop Speech recognitionTask. try this one might help

```
        if audioEngine.inputNode.numberOfInputs > 0 {
            audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        }
```

stop audio once recording finish

```
 func finishSpeech(){
    audioEngine.stop() //AVAudioEngine()
    recognitionTask?.cancel() //speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask
    request.endAudio()  //SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
    audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
 }
```

posting answer behalf of your explanation. this might help

Comment: Great kindly accept answer by clicking on tick with answer it might help others